# How does `kotlin.internal.contracts.ContractBuilderKt#contract` work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, and when I read the implementation of `let`, I see this:

```
contract {
    callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
}
return block(this)
```

What is `contract` here? Is there any efficiency cost for calling that method?

I cannot call `contract` in my own project since it's `internal`..

Comment: 'contract' is also used in many other places in Standard.kt - like `apply()` , `also()` , `with()` , `run()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`contract` is additional metadata that will be used in future versions of the Kotlin compiler for better code analysis. The contact annotations do not have any effect in Kotlin 1.2.x.

Comment: Oh Thank♂you♂sir